# IE 8 and below Conditional Comments not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments, html5shiv

I have a conditional comment that checks if IE is less than version 9.

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/polyfill/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/polyfill/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
```

When I take out the comments, the scripts run fine, but they wont work when the comments are there. The syntax seems to be correct(unless I missed something).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you testing this in a _real_ IE 8? One of the problems with the several tools out there that offer various different IE versions in one package is that conditional comments tend _not_ to work …

Comment: Ah..that could be why. I am using a tool instead of the real browser.

Comment: i am not an expert but doesn't the syntax should be <!--[endif]-->

Comment: @rajkumarts: No, the whole thing from `<!--` to `-->` is a comment for other browsers.

Comment: Can't get <!--[if IE]> to work on ie 11.0.96

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug as reported here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806767/conditional-comments-do-not-work-when-emulating-document-modes-via-f12-developer-tools